# How to store profile picture and after login retrieve it into uiimageview using PARSE

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

I would like to know how to store profile picture in sign up screen where is 1 UIImageView and few Uitextfields. My problem is, that I don't know how to select picture from camera or photo library and choose one which will be upload to parse database. Second problem is that I am not able to retrieve this photo to UIImageView. I wasn't able to find any tutorial to this. If anyone knows something helpful I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

A nice tutorial that is going to show you how to create a login service and upload a profile picture representing the user : http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12

Comment: I don't want to create login service. I'm using parse, this tutorial is useless for my problem, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For picking an image you'll have to use UIImagePickerController, for uploading it, you'll have to convert the image into a PFFile and thus upload it.

Here's a great tutorial that might help you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6kTw_cK3zY
In addition to this tutorial, look into his channel for a tutorial where he "upgrades" and also adding profile images

Answer (score 0):

You can form data using post method By creating key value pair for all field and also set image Base64 image data in one key value pair. Example

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Folllow this URl https://www.parse.com/tutorials/saving-images will be helpful...find "Uploading Photos".